# powershell string interpolation in Shell.Application

Tags: powershell, script

I have a PowerShell script;

```
$filex = Get-ChildItem C:\somewhere\anotherfolder\anotherfolder\lastfolder\ -recurse -Filter *coolfile.exe
$ShellExp = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$ShellExp.open("{$filex} http://speedtest.tele2.net/10MB.zip %appdata%\101x.zip")
```

What should I do to execute $filex ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're asking the same question as this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44035920/7537973
In which case the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44036090/7537973

Tl;dr put the function inside of $() so in your example it would be `$ShellExp.open("$(Get-ChildItem C:\somewhere\anotherfolder\anotherfolder\lastfolder\ -recurse -Filter *coolfile.exe) http://speedtest.tele2.net/10MB.zip %appdata%\101x.zip")`